# Pyscreenshot doesnt to work when i use the module 'keyboard'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that reads text from a screenshot and copies it to my clipboard, but when i try to give my variables the value i want with my mouse cords Python will quit unexpectedly with a long crash report.

I've tried to reinstall the modules i use, I've tried to run the code on my 2nd computer and i have of cause tried to find the answer on google without any luck.

When i give x1,y1,x2,y2 the values with my mouse cords it wont work, but if i instead just declare x1,y1,x2,y2 as the same values that i would have gotten with the mouse cords it works fine.

```
root = Tk()
print("xy1")
keyboard.wait('s')# wait until 'space' is pressed
x1 = root.winfo_pointerx() # get the x pos from mouse
y1 = root.winfo_pointery() # get the x pos from mouse
print(x1,y1)
keyboard.wait('s')# wait until 'space' is pressed
x2 = root.winfo_pointerx() # get the x pos from mouse
y2 = root.winfo_pointery() # get the y pos from mouse
print(x2,y2)
image = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2)) #screenshot selected part of screen
```

Is there a way to get it to work or is there a better way to select the area i want?

Btw i am using macOS.

Comment: is yours quitting?

Comment: I just ran into this issue on a code I had working just fine in April, but something changed since then I guess. I solved by image = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2), childprocess=False)